# VueJs not working on Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I just installed fresh `laravel` and `npm` + `vue-axios` & `vue-router` but somehow mycomponents wont load.

## code

`App.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

import App from './App.vue';

import examplecomponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';

//settings
import settings from './components/admin/settings/Index.vue';
import passportclients from './components/passport/Clients.vue';
import passportauthorizedclients from './components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue';
import passportpersonalaccesstokens from './components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue';


const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: examplecomponent,
        name: 'examplecomponent'
    },
    {
        path: '/settings',
        component: settings,
        name: 'settings'
    },
    {path: 
        '/passportclients',
        component: passportclients,
        name: 'passportclients'
    },
    {path: 
        '/passportauthorizedclients',
        component: passportauthorizedclients,
        name: 'passportauthorizedclients'
    },
    {path: 
        'passportpersonalaccesstokens',
        component: passportpersonalaccesstokens,
        name: 'passportpersonalaccesstokens'
    },
];

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes});
new Vue(Vue.util.extend({ router }, App)).$mount('#app');
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue-axios": "^2.1.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
    }
}
```

any idea why i cannot get my components?

Comment: Did you miss 'npm run build' ?

Comment: Your `App.js` is syntactically invalid. You cannot use `import` after any procedural code

Comment: @ManoharKhadka i didn't use that code

Comment: @Phil please show me what should i use? but in `npm run watch` i don't get any error

Comment: All `imports` must be at the top of your module

Comment: @Phil same result bro, not loading

Comment: @ManoharKhadka I get `npm ERR! missing script: build` on `npm run build`

Comment: If you are using any of `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` that should be fine..And the issue might be something else then.